# Fetch a random photo from Google Photos with API

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

I want to write an app that fetches a random photo from my Google Photos set of photos using the Google Photos API. This is the new Google Photos, not the old one that was linked to a Google Drive.

In my review of the [API Docs](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/overview), it seems that you can list albums, and perhaps list what the albums contain, but it's not obvious to me how to download a photo itself. Can anyone figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this API: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/list

It lets you list the photos from your library and returns two parameters, productUrl and baseUrl, that you could use to get the photo.